# How to generate discontinuous timeline in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=601919.SS+Interactive#symbol=601919.ss;range=1d;compare=;indicator=volume;charttype=area;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=off;source=undefined;

I want to merge the point from `11:30` to `13:00` to decrease the width of the pic (during time is lunch break).

code:

```
                    xAxis: {
                    type: "datetime",
                    min: Date.UTC(2013,8,27,1,29,0),
                    max: Date.UTC(2013,8,27,7,59,0)
                    }
```

can someone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a heavily requested feature in highcharts. You can read he comments and add your vote here: http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/2706364-allow-irregular-time-series-to-skip-nights-and-wee

Comment: thank you,i will vote.But how to deal with that before the official update?

Comment: You can use [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickPositioner) and check dates, if is saturday/sunday then skip